# Create random numbers with left skewed probability distribution

Tags: python, statistics

I would like to pick a number randomly between 1-100 such that the probability of getting numbers 60-100 is higher than 1-59.

I would like to have the probability to be a left-skewed distribution for numbers 1-100. That is to say, it has a long tail and a peak.

Something along the lines:

```
pers = np.arange(1,101,1)
prob = <left-skewed distribution>
number = np.random.choice(pers, 1, p=prob)
```

I do not know how to generate a left-skewed discrete probability function. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you described, just make sure your skewed-distribution adds up to 1.0:

```
pers = np.arange(1,101,1)

# Make each of the last 41 elements 5x more likely
prob = [1.0]*(len(pers)-41) + [5.0]*41

# Normalising to 1.0
prob /= np.sum(prob)

number = np.random.choice(pers, 1, p=prob)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am really looking for a distribution of probability rather than a fixed value between ranges. For example, I would like the probability to vary such that is it has a distinct peak and a long tail. This is what I mean by left-skew.

Comment: @aging_gorrila: Well, there are many ways to do so. what are your numbers representing? From your answer, you'll probably find you can simply stick to the usual np.random.normal, np.random.poisson...

Comment: Yes, that would help. I guess the link to your example did not come through. Could you post it again?

Comment: If you just need an example of skewed distribution, you can use this simple binomial example. The total number of "head", after 100 throws of coin, assuming head:tail probability of 0.8:0.2: prob=np.random.binomial(100, 0.8, 100). This returns 100 random numbers, between 0 and 100 included, with a peak probability at 80.

Answer (score 12):

This is the answer you are looking for using the SciPy function 'skewnorm'. It can make any positive set of integers either left or rightward skewed.

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numValues = 10000
maxValue = 100
skewness = -5   #Negative values are left skewed, positive values are right skewed.

random = skewnorm.rvs(a = skewness,loc=maxValue, size=numValues)  #Skewnorm function

random = random - min(random)      #Shift the set so the minimum value is equal to zero.
random = random / max(random)      #Standadize all the vlues between 0 and 1. 
random = random * maxValue         #Multiply the standardized values by the maximum value.

#Plot histogram to check skewness
plt.hist(random,30,density=True, color = 'red', alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Please reference the documentation here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html

[Histogram of left-skewed distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXcb8.png)

The code generates the following plot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The p argument of np.random.choice is the probability associated with each element in the array in the first argument. So something like:

```
    np.random.choice(pers, 1, p=[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, ..... , 0.02, 0.02])
```

Where 0.01 is the lower probability for 1-59 and 0.02 is the higher probability for 60-100.

The SciPy documentation has some useful examples.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

EDIT:
You might also try this link and look for a distribution (about half way down the page) that fits the model you are looking for.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Comment: thanks but as I explained above, I am looking for a distribution and not fixed values.

Comment: I added a new link that has some distributions that should fit what you are looking for.