# Drawing trials from asymmetric error distribution (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, random, data-science, montecarlo

I'm running a quick Monte Carlo error analysis. One of the parameters I'm looking at has a non-Gaussian error distribution; let's say Log10[param] = 9.33 +0.21 -0.01. In NumPy, how would I draw trials from a distribution centered at the parameter representing these asymmetric errors?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a non-gaussian distribution? Would, for example, a skewed gaussian distribution work for your purposes?

Comment: A skewed Gaussian would be perfect here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create random numbers with left skewed probability distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854965/create-random-numbers-with-left-skewed-probability-distribution)

Comment: Your question is essentially unanswerable because there are an infinite number of non-Gaussian distributions. (Literally any function with f(x) > 0 for all x and having a finite area can be rescaled to be a valid distribution.) You’ve provided no basis for picking any particular one of that infinite set.